# Saving NSDate error in Swift 3 and iOS 10

Tags: ios8, swift3, xcode8

I believe this is a bug introduced in the new stack probably Swift 3 / iOS 10. I am running on XCode8 / Swift3 / iPhone 7 (Simulator) / ios 10.0 I have not found any related report of it.

1. set the value

   ```
   let dt : Date? = Date()
   UserDefaults.standard.set(dt, forKey: "test-date")
   ```
2. Get the value

   ```
   let dt = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "test-date")
   if dt == nil {
     return false
   }
   else {
     let date = dt! as Date // FAILED
   }
   ```

The failed message is:

> Could not cast value of type '__NSCFData' (0x10fa08500) to 'NSDate' (0x10fa08f00).

Not sure how the object is converted to NSData instead of NSDate.

Comment: I'd suggest resetting "test-date" value, as you must have accidentally set it to a `Data()` rather than a `Date()` at some point. When I store a use your code, it works fine (though that cast syntax doesn't look right; I used `if let date = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "test-date") as? Date { ... }`).

Comment: An answer below (which I think should be deleted) suggests that this question is superceded [by this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39518680/xcode-8-swift-3-userdefaults-standard-set-nil-error).